# calculate the second singular value

Tags: svd

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
                0.5  &  0.5  & &  & & \\
                  &  0.5  & 0.5& & & \\
                  &  & \ddots & \ddots &   \\
                   &  & & \ddots  &   0.5\\
                0.5 &   &  & &0.5\\
                \end{bmatrix}$$
I need to calculate the first and second singular values, and I know the first is $1$, please tell me how to get the second.

Comment: This might be mosquitoes with canons, but your matrix is [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Comment: I find a way just use power method, this matrix is good. But I can't get a generous answer with $n$.

Comment: @Arthur I did it with circulant. Thanks.